# Invoice paid date in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm trying to find the date when Invoice was paid in magento.

I know that `sales_flat_invoice` has `created_at` and `updated_at` fields, but I need to know exactly the date when an invoice was paid?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the payment method you have configured and the customer has selected for his order. For example bank prepayment payment methods do not implement such a feature. You just wait for the customers payment and when the deposit arrives, you create an invoice. The invoice gets status **paid** immediately.
On the other hand, payment methods by misc. payment provider extension implement a **capture** and a **deposit** action. When the customer orders, an invoice is generated automatically with status **pending** and right after the payment has been deposited by the provider, the invoice status may change to **paid** - again - automatically in background

Comment: And where usually this deposit action is logged? So reading this log I will know the exact date of payment?